# How to group on a pandas dataframe considering average and sum of columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe pandas:

```
      import pandas as pd
      df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1a','1a','3a','4a','3a'],
                         'column_1': [10.6, 10.4, 10, 20, 20],
                         'column_2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
                        })

      print(df)

     ID   column_1  column_2
     1a   10.6        10
     1a   10.4        20
     3a   10.0        30
     4a   20.0        40
     3a   20.0        50
```

I need to do a grouping so 'ID'. So I did this:

```
      df_result = df.groupby(['ID'])
```

Now, I would like to group by the average of the column_1 and the sum of the 'column_2'. But I was only able to do the average operation:

```
      df_result.mean()
```

Output:

```
       column_1 column_2
   ID       
   1a   10.5    15
   3a   15.0    40
   4a   20.0    40
```

desired output:

```
   ID   column_1    column_2
   1a   10.5         30
   3a   15.0         80
   4a   20.0         30
```

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').agg({'column_1': 'mean', 'column_2': 'sum'})`

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').agg({'column_1':'mean', 'column_2': 'sum'})`.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I would like to ask how can I adjust the indexes, that is, the names of the columns as a normal table?

Comment: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'column_1': 'mean', 'column_2': 'sum'})`